# Using jquery autocomplete in asp.net GridView to postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, autocomplete, postback

I have a somewhat unique situation where I need to perform a postback on a field I am doing a jquery autolookup.

Here is how I do the jquery now, it uses a CssClass to find the textbox:

```
$(".txtWorkCode").autocomplete({
    source: "SearchFill.aspx?ControlInfo=Expense", 
    minLength: 2
});
```

This work fine, but the field doing the autocomplete has to do a postback upon getting the looked up value (to populate another field in the row).
I cannot use a conventional onBlur or onTextChanged because I get back the values I typed in to do the autolookup (it is  short-curcuited ).

I need for the jQuery to initiate the postback.  I have tried various versions of:

```
.result(function (event, item)
```

but none have worked. I am using UI 1.8.9. for autocomplete.

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Could you hook into the select event for the autocomplete function to perform an async postback?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#event-select

> Triggered when an item is selected
>   from the menu; ui.item refers to the
>   selected item. The default action of
>   select is to replace the text field's
>   value with the value of the selected
>   item. Canceling this event prevents
>   the value from being updated, but does
>   not prevent the menu from closing.

That's straight from the jQueryUI site.

Comment: OK thanks szeliga - I was able to involke a postback using this: select: function (event, item) { __doPostBack('AddMarkup', item.item.value); } - wierd item.item looks like an array or something.  but it works!

Comment: it is probably just JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) more info on that here:http://www.json.org/  Also, if you need this postback to happen for other elements, you could do __doPostBack('<%# control.ClientID%>', item.item.value); where control is the control that you want to have postback.